Where is the Gold Track Security Lane at DTW?
I fly regularly out of the Evans Terminal at Detroit Metropolitan Wayne County Airport (DTW/KDTW). According to the Star Alliance website, this airport should have Gold Track access for passengers with Star Alliance Gold status (which I have); however, I have yet to see any signage corresponding to this at the regular (non-TSA PreCheck) security checkpoint, and I'm always processed as any other passenger. I admittedly haven't checked whether it's located at the TSA PreCheck checkpoint, since I don't currently qualify for the latter.
As all Star Alliance flights (United, Air Canada, Lufthansa, and Turkish Airlines) at DTW use the Evans Terminal, I would assume that if Gold Track indeed exists at this airport, it would certainly be available at that terminal.
Where specifically inside the terminal might I find it?

https://www.staralliance.com/en/airport-information?airportCode=DTW#goldTrack says "Look For: Premier Access and Gold Track" but does not give more details. Nothing visible on Street View (probably the airport with the least signage I have ever seen), not better on the terminal map on their website.

https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/united-airlines-mileageplus/2071708-airports-premier-access-security-lanes-2.html says "DTW has a Gold Track premier access line but it has never been open in my 10+ departures over the past two years, including peak and non-peak times" (2 years ago).

@jcaron that's interesting, but I do wonder how up-to-date their post is (given it was made in 2022) -- the other information in it doesn't match at all with my experience with United check-in at this airport.

Given you regularly fly out of there, it may be worthwhile simply asking at the Lufthansa Lounge next time you are there.
